# How to write data to a file continuously without blocking main loop in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, file, asynchronous

I am new to Python and I have a scenario where I want to write measurement data to 2 files, one file within the `main()` function and another file within a function `WriteToFile()` which writes a new line of data every 10 seconds.
How can I make `WriteFile()` get fired once in the `main()` loop and then run until 2 minutes after the `main()` loop iteration completes? How can I then exit `WriteToFile()` gracefully in `CleanUp()`, ensuring that `FastFile.txt` has closed properly?
Here is a simplified program example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import time
import sys
import random

M_Max = 2000
M_Array = [740] 
D_Array = [5, 10, 20, 100, 150, 200, 400,600, 740]  



M=random.random()*20000
D=random.random()*7500


#write data to a file every ten seconds  
def WriteToFile():  
    while True:
        h = open("FastFile.txt", "a")
        current_time_t=datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S")
        p = random.random()*1000
        c = random.random()*100
        
        print("Fast_Time :", '{} {:9.0f} {:9.0f} {:9.3f} {:9.1f}  '.format(current_time_t, M, D, p, c))

        h.write("\n %s , %s , %s , %s, %s  " % (current_time_t, str('{:.1f}'.format(M)), str('{:.1f}'.format(D)), str('{:.3f}'.format(p)), str('{:.2f}'.format(
        c))))
        h.close()
        time.sleep(10)

    
        
    

def CleanUp():
    print("Cleaning up")
    
    #wait two minutes then stop WriteToFile()
    time.sleep(120)
    sys.exit()
    
    print("Done")
    


def main():
    global  M, D
   
    WriteToFile()  # call this function and start writing data including the global variables M and N generated here

    print("Starting measurement")
    time.sleep(3)
    
    for M in M_Array:

        for D in D_Array:  
            
            p = random.random()*1000
            c = random.random()*100

            g = open("SlowFile.txt", "a")
            

            current_time_t = datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S")

            print("Main_Time :", '{} {:9.0f} {:9.0f} {:9.3f} {:9.1f}  '.format(current_time_t, M, D, p, c))
            
            #write the result of each iteration to a file
            g.write("\n %s , %s , %s , %s, %s  " % (current_time_t, str('{:.1f}'.format(M)), str('{:.1f}'.format(D)), str('{:.3f}'.format(p)), str('{:.2f}'.format(
                c))))
            g.close()


    CleanUp()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am using `Python 3.5.3` but can upgrade to accommodate solutions that require higher versions of Python.

Comment: you can use multiprocessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `threading`!
Your `if __name__="__main__"` has to be like below:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=WriteToFile)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=loop) # put the loop in a new function and call it using this
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

Your `main()` function has to be renamed to loop or anything you like, without the call to `WriteToFile()`.
Remember to import threading at the beginning of the code.

Comment: Thanks very much. This solved my problem.